# How do I get user inputs from edittext and displayed in another edittext on the same activity

Tags: android

I am making a currency converter with two edittext and I intend to get input from edittext view and displaying it in the second edittext. I am wondering how this can be accompanished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class TestEditTextListener extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText firstEditText;
    private EditText secondEditText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        firstEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstEditText);
        secondEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.secondEditText);


        firstEditText.addTextChangedListener(new EditTextListener());

    }

    private class EditTextListener implements TextWatcher {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            secondEditText.setText(firstEditText.getText());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean :D

Comment: yeah Mistakenly I post the same answer on other thread too. :D . never mind

Answer (score 1):

Use a **Button** to get the value from EditText1 and Set the Value for EditText2

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           //Any Modification/process u need to do with the input can be done here
            editText2.setText(editText1.getText().toString()); 
        }
    });
```